# Images inside a popover

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, tooltip, popover

I'm having an issue with my popover as follow:

I have a popover with some PHP generated content and no fixed height and want to insert an image in that popover. The tip floats over my element like so:

[image: http://puu.sh/cAzaT/1868ff29b8.jpg]

The issue is that if that the image isn't preloaded in the dom, it is loaded when the popover is created but because the popover is displayed before the image has fully loaded, it displays the tip without the image and gives it a height of 30px, then loads the image which displace the tooltip down like this

[image]

Is there a way to load the tooltip content (show a loading gif?) before displaying it?

I could get away with a fixed height but my images have different sizes so it won't look great.

Hope I made this clear enough.

Answer (score 0):

Try preloading the images with JavaScript:

```
if (document.images) {
img1 = new Image(75,22); img1.src = "img1.png";
img2 = new Image(75,22); img2.src = "img2.png";
}
```

**EDIT:** If you have hundreds of images and you don't want to load them all, place loader.gif under your image, only preloading loader.gif.